Using statevector in latest version of qiskit==1.0
I am trying to use migrate my code from old version of qiskit to the latest version qiskit==1.0 for the  statevector.
import numpy as np
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
     
backend = AerSimulator(method='statevector')
        
backend.set_options(
    max_parallel_threads = 0,
    max_parallel_experiments = 0,
    max_parallel_shots = 1,
    statevector_parallel_threshold = 16     
)
        
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)
qc_combine = pm.run(qc_combine)
        
result = backend.run(qc_combine, shots= 1)
    
psi_out_complex = result.result()

Not sure how to put the statevector in the variable psi_out_complex. Presently what I have in  psi_out_complex is as below:
(Pdb) psi_out_complex
Result(backend_name='aer_simulator_statevector', backend_version='0.14.2', qobj_id='', job_id='690d4191-80ae-40d3-b3e8-96ad1098cf21', success=True, results=[ExperimentResult(shots=1, success=True, meas_level=2, data=ExperimentResultData(), header=QobjExperimentHeader(creg_sizes=[], global_phase=0.0, memory_slots=0, n_qubits=2, name='circuit-166', qreg_sizes=[['q', 2]], metadata={}), status=DONE, seed_simulator=4294967295, metadata={'time_taken': 3.2642e-05, 'num_bind_params': 1, 'required_memory_mb': 1, 'input_qubit_map': [], 'method': 'statevector', 'device': 'CPU', 'num_qubits': 0, 'parallel_state_update': 32, 'active_input_qubits': [], 'num_clbits': 0, 'remapped_qubits': False, 'parallel_shots': 1, 'runtime_parameter_bind': False, 'max_memory_mb': 257792, 'measure_sampling': False, 'batched_shots_optimization': False}, time_taken=3.2642e-05)], date=2024-07-27T00:53:22.831294, status=COMPLETED, header=None, metadata={'time_taken_parameter_binding': 5.481e-06, 'time_taken_execute': 6.312e-05, 'omp_enabled': True, 'max_gpu_memory_mb': 0, 'max_memory_mb': 257792, 'parallel_experiments': 1}, time_taken=0.0009953975677490234)
(Pdb) type(psi_out_complex)
<class 'qiskit.result.result.Result'>

I am doing something wrong. It would be great help if someone can help with this issue.
The link I am using is: https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/tutorials/1_aersimulator.html#Simulating-a-Quantum-Circuit

You can use save_statevector() to save a statevector. Here's a related post here
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
import numpy as np

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0, 1)
circ.save_statevector() #save the system's statevector

backend = AerSimulator(method='statevector')
    
backend.set_options(
    max_parallel_threads = 0,
    max_parallel_experiments = 0,
    max_parallel_shots = 1,
    statevector_parallel_threshold = 16     
)

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)
qc_combine = pm.run(circ)

result = backend.run(qc_combine, shots= 1)
psi_out_complex = result.result()
print(psi_out_complex.get_statevector())

Statevector([0.70710678+0.j, 0.        +0.j, 0.        +0.j,
             0.70710678+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))


Thank you @taketoshikinoshita for great help.
